# Methods in object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, object, this

```
// Given the object:
var employee = {
  name: "John Smith",
  job: "Programmer",
  age: 31,
  
  }
}

// Add a method called nameLength that prints out the
// length of the employees name to the console.
```

i am making one method but not getting the length of the name

```
nameLength: function(){
    console.log(this.name.length);
```

Comment: Did you place the `nameLength: …` in the empty line? Because the two code snippets you posted appear to be incomplete, one has a `}` too much the other one too few.

Comment: Can you show us how you are calling that method? What happens instead when you are "*not getting the length of the name*"?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by assigning your function to a property named `nameLength` on your object:

```js
var employee = { name: "John Smith", job: "Programmer", age: 31 };
employee.nameLength = function() {
  console.log(this.name.length);
};

employee.nameLength();
```

You can also add it when you are defining your object:

```js
var employee = {
  name: "John Smith",
  job: "Programmer",
  age: 31,
  nameLength: function() {
    console.log(this.name.length);
  },
};

employee.nameLength();
```